# iOS13: When I try to open a UIViewController in landscape mode, the application freezes

Tags: ios, ios13

When I try to open on iOS13 a UIViewController in landscape mode, the application freezes. (if you do not rotate the screen before, if you rotate the phone in your hands before opening this screen, then the frieze will not happen). It worked well on previous versions.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

How can i overcome this problem? looks like a bug on Apple's side

---

In freezings moment in console I see

> XPC connection interrupted

Comment: Seems to be a Simulator Bug. Closing and restarting the simulator helped my with this problem.

Comment: I have this problem with iPhone (6s on iOS13)

Answer (score 0):

Reload Simulator. I've had with UIAlertView the same bug